# Raster: How to get elevation at lat/long using python?

Tags: python, gdal, elevation

I also posted this question in the GIS section of SO. As I'm not sure if this rather a 'pure' python question I also ask it here again.

I was wondering if anyone has some experience in getting elevation data from a raster **without using ArcGIS**, but rather get the information as a python `list` or `dict`?

I get my XY data as a list of tuples.

I'd like to loop through the list or pass it to a function or class-method to get the corresponding elevation for the xy-pairs.

I did some research on the topic and the **gdal** API sounds promising. Can anyone advice me how to go about things, pitfalls, sample code? Other options?

Thanks for your efforts, LarsVegas

Answer (score 2):

I recommend checking out the [Google Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/)

It's very straightforward to use:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=39.7391536,-104.9847034&sensor=true_or_false

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "elevation" : 1608.637939453125,
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 39.73915360,
            "lng" : -104.98470340
         },
         "resolution" : 4.771975994110107
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

note that the free version is limited to 2500 requests per day.

Comment: Actually I wanna use my own elevation data (which has a resolution of 0.5x0.5m).

Answer (score 1):

We used this code to get elevation for a given latitude/longitude (NOTE: we only asked to print the elevation, and the rounded lat and long values).

```
import urllib.request
import json
lati = input("Enter the latitude:")
lngi = input("Enter the longitude:")

# url_params completes the base url with the given latitude and longitude values
ELEVATION_BASE_URL = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?'
URL_PARAMS = "locations=%s,%s&sensor=%s" % (lati, lngi, "false")
url=ELEVATION_BASE_URL + URL_PARAMS
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as f:
response = json.loads(f.read().decode())    
status = response["status"]
result = response["results"][0]
print(float(result["elevation"]))
print(float(result["location"]["lat"]))
print(float(result["location"]["lng"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [altimeter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/altimeter) a wrapper for the Google Elevation API

Answer (score -1):

Here is the another one nice API that I`v built: https://algorithmia.com/algorithms/Gaploid/Elevation

```
import Algorithmia

input = {
    "lat": "50.2111",
    "lon": "18.1233"
}
client = Algorithmia.client('YOUR_API_KEY')
algo = client.algo('Gaploid/Elevation/0.3.0')
print algo.pipe(input)
```